# Set focus on first-child <li> item that has <a> tag in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having a bit issue figuring out how to select only the first child in a li tag that has a link in it.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label</li>
  <li><a href="#">Select Me</a> </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li:first-child a').focus();
```

In this particular case it doesn't get past the list item that is the "Label"

Comment: `dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li a').first().focus()`, but perhaps you meant `.dropdown-menu > li > a`, which would make a difference in nested drop-down menus, and behave more robustly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eq` method.

> eq method reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the
>   specified index.

```js
$('body').find('.dropdown-menu li a').eq(0).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 1</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 2</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Select Me</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Another method is to use `:first` **pseudo-selector**.

> first method reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the
>   set.

```
$('body').find('.dropdown-menu li a:first').css('color','red');
```

```js
$('body').find('.dropdown-menu li a:first').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label</li>
  <li><a href="#">Select Me</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Also, another solution that can help you is to use `$.each` method in order to search for the **first** `li` which has hyperlink element.

```js
$('ul li').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('a').length>0){
    $(this).find('a').css('color','red');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="true">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 1</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 2</li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Label 3</li>
  <li><a href="#">Select Me</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: using dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li a').eq(0).focus(); does the job.

Comment: @zemaker, glad to help

Comment: @zemaker, also, i provided you three solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about `$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').first()`?